# Why is the line getting printed multiple times?

Tags: java, while-loop

I want the line `"Enter character: "` to be printed, then take the input character and assign it, and then keep redoing that till a `-` or `?` is the input. However, `"Enter character: "` gets printed multiple times after the first input after being printed once initially. Entering a `'?'` or `'-'` doesn't exit the loop either.

Here is the method:

```
    private void runPrompt() {
    Deque<Character> first = new Deque<Character>();
    Deque<Character> second = new Deque<Character>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    char userChar = 0;
    int firstWord = 0;
    int secondWord = 0;
    boolean isMinus = false;
    while (!isMinus) {
        System.out.print("Enter character: ");
        try {
            userChar = (char) reader.read();
            System.out.println(userChar);
            first.enqueue(userChar);
            firstWord++;
            if (userChar == '-') {
                isMinus = true;
            }
        } catch (QueueException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (isMinus) {
        while (userChar != '?') {
            System.out.print("Enter character: ");
            try {
                userChar = (char) reader.read();
                System.out.println(userChar);
                second.enqueue(userChar);
                secondWord++;
            } catch (QueueException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    switch (checkLength(firstWord, secondWord, isMinus)) {
    case 0:
        System.out.print("\t>>Same length, ");
        if (checkContent(first, second)) {
            System.out.print("Same content, ");
            if (checkPalindrome(first, firstWord)) {
                System.out.println("Palindrome");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Different content, no Palindrome");
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        System.out
                .println("\t>>Left longer, different content, no Palindrome");
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out
                .println("\t>>Right longer, different content, no Palindrome");
        break;

    case 3:
        System.out.println("\t>>No minus");

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is how the sample output:

```
    Enter character: r
    r
    Enter character: 

    Enter character: 

    Enter character:
```

Comment: clear the buffer after reading a single line using `readLine()`

Comment: `if (userChar == '-') { isMinus = true; }` should be written `isMinus = userChar == '-';`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I use `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it reads character by character, it actually reads r, then a carriage return (CR) character, and finally a line feed (LF) character. You can print the value & see for yourself:

```
System.out.println((int)userChar);
```

It shows the UTF-16 code-unit values of the characters I mentioned. So per input, the loop will execute two more times. Then it comes back & waits for the next input - that's why a total of four `Enter character:` statements are visible. You could just use something like `readLine().charAt(0)` to avoid this. There is probably some method to flush pending inputs in the buffer, but am not recollecting it right now.

Comment: Java String, char and Character use Unicode/UTF-16 so instead of ASCII say UTF-16 code-unit value.